# Which socket.io function gets triggered immediately when user goes offline?

Tags: android, socket.io

I am using `disconnect` event on server side to detect when a user's internet is disconnected. But whenever WIFI is turned off from client's device, I've noticed that the function gets triggered after about 20 seconds. Is there any other socket.io event which gets triggered even before `disconnect` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server, the `disconnecting` event comes just slightly before the `disconnect` event, but the difference in timing is probably not material. `disconnecting` is triggered right before the socket has been removed from any rooms it is in whereas the `disconnect` is right after.  I doubt the `disconnecting` event will improve your situation at all as the difference in timing between the two is very small.

When the connection/transport is broken, the TCP socket is not closed and the server does not immediately know they've lost a connection.  As far as it's concerned, it still has an open socket to the client.

socket.io engages in end-to-end heartbeats so at some point, the server will realize that the heartbeat has stopped.  How long it is before the server realizes the heartbeat is missing depends upon a number of things, some situational and some based on configuration.

For example if the server just got a successful heartbeat from the client right before the connection was broken, then it will be an entire heartbeat cycle before the server has any idea that the next heartbeat is missing.  If, on the other hand, the connection is broken right before a heartbeat was scheduled, then the server will notice sooner.

In addition, there are various configuration options (time outs) that determine how long the server waits for a re-established connection before it gives up and determines the connection is disconnected.

You can examine the `pingTimeout` and `pingInterval` configuration options for the server as described in [the doc here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#pingtimeout). Shortening those will allow the server to realize the client has disconnected sooner, but it also adds small load to both client and server, uses a little more bandwidth and may impact how much battery power a remote device uses - so be careful with making these values too short.

Comment: Update to the link since old one is broken: https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#pingtimeout

Comment: @theknightD2 - Thx, I updated the answer.

Comment: You're welcome!